# How to use/convert xml string as parameter in xsl transformation

Tags: php, html, xml, xslt

My code builds an xml output from mysql dataset. Then I need to transform it to HTML. I saved it in a php variable and tried to use it in **transformToXML( $XML )** as parameter but it raises it expects an object here. How do I convert this xml output to an object to be used as a parameter here.  Here is my code:

```
<?php

// i am using the resultset to build an XML DOM but you can do whatever you like with it !

   header("Content-type: text/xml");
   $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "babar", "k4541616", "spec", 3306);
   // one non-recursive db call to get the message tree !
   $result = $conn->query("call message_hier(1)");
   //--$result = $conn->query("call message_hier_all()");
   $xml = new DomDocument;
   $xpath = new DOMXpath($xml);
   $msgs = $xml->createElement("messages");
   $xml->appendChild($msgs);
   // loop and build the DOM
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
     $msg = $xml->createElement("message");
     foreach($row as $col => $val) $msg->setAttribute($col, $val); 

   if(is_null($row["parent_msg_id"])){
     $msgs->appendChild($msg);
   }
   else{
     $qry = sprintf("//*[@msg_id = '%d']", $row["parent_msg_id"]);
     $parent = $xpath->query($qry)->item(0);
     if(!is_null($parent)) $parent->appendChild($msg);
    } 
   }
   $result->close();
   $conn->close();
   $save = $xml->saveXML();//-> Here i save mxl in php var
   //echo $save;

   $xslt = new XSLTProcessor();
   $XSL = new DOMDocument();
   $XSL->load( 'msg.xsl');
   $xslt->importStylesheet( $XSL );
   header('Content-Type: application/xml');
   print $xslt->transformToXML($save); //->error: expects an object here, string given.

  ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to turn your XML string back into an object via `DOMDocument::loadXML()` before you can use it.

Comment: Well, you could call the `save()` method on it if you like. See the link.

Comment: Actually I want to ask where should I use it? If you mean to use in last line to print results i.e. "print $xslt->transformToDoc( $save )" then I used it & same result. Or you mention to use it earlier to convert xml to domdoc ?

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that you use `$XML` but you mean `$xml`.

Comment: sorry, may be I did not clear things very well & use of caps make some confusion for you. If you see on my code, I am getting an xml output through "$xml->saveXML()" that I saved like "$save=$xml->saveXML();". Now I need to give "$xslt->transformToXML();" an xml parameter, I here used $save but it raises error that it expects an object here, string given. Now I need to know how could I convert the response from   "$xml->saveXML()" to a form so that it could be used as a parameter for "$xslt->transformToXML();". So this is my whole problem.

Comment: You don't. You pass it `$xml`.

Comment: OH OK, sorry, raelly very sorry, I put a comment there & realized that people will understand I need to use $save here. So I hope you now understand my problem.

Comment: Well, if you *need* to use `$save` then you have to turn it back into an object first via `DOMDocument::loadXML()`.